# SequelizeJs and Model Definition

Tags: sqlite, orm

I have a table which has approximately 100 columns. I want to create a model for the table in sequelizeJs (ORM for NodeJs and SQLite) . My question is, can we split a Model definition into multiple files in Sequelize? I am doing it for the sake of Modularity in the code

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. François Zaninotto provides a nice guide on how to do this by leveraging a models.index file with some helper functions.

[Sequelize, the JavaScript ORM, in practice](http://redotheweb.com/2013/02/20/sequelize-the-javascript-orm-in-practice.html)